# GNUradio QT GUI Time Sink plot colour and line widths configuration

Tags: qt, plot, qtgui, gnuradio-companion

In GNU Radio Companion, version 3.10.9.2, running on a Windows 10 PC, I am trying to plot two complex signals using the QT GUI Time Sink. The real part of the second complex signal "vco input" is not showing because its colour is white (on white background). Also the real part of the first complex input "I" is shown with a wrong line width, although all plots have a line width (1). I'm trying to configure the line colours and widths and the plot doesn't change, or sometimes it changes, and most of the time it doesn't. Line style and line Labels work as expected.
[[image: The legent shows that the colour is white on white, although I configured it as cyan]]

I can configure the plot while it is running, but not by using the config menu inside the block. Any idea what I'm doing wrong or where to find instructions on how to configure the plot?

Comment: Until now I've found that the theme selection (under tools in GRC) changes the colours and line widths but unfortunately in an unknown/undocumented way. When I select the dark.qss all line colours change to green and the "vco plot" is visible. The config values of line colours and widths is ignored. This workaround makes me think that I'm missing a crucial document.